# Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на весь svg(даже на дырки в картинке) открывалась ссылка?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал ссылку в svg, работает нормально, но хочу чтобы даже при наведении на дырки этой svg на ссылку можно было всё ещё кликнуть. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите всю вашу svg картинку в ссылку. Это будет выглядеть как-то так

```
<a href="#"><svg>...</svg></a>
```

или же так

```
<a href="#"><img src="1.svg"></a>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень сильно помогли новичку, который еле как пытается ночью сделать сайт!

Comment: пожалуйста, если ответ получен, то отметьте как отвеченный.